# Spring Boot REST controller classpath

Tags: rest, spring-boot

We're starting a Spring Boot app with `gradle bootRun` which triggers the `x.Application` class which has the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`.  After starting we can access REST services in the `x` package but can't access REST services in other packages. How can you configure the classpath accordingly?

Comment: Sound like a component scan problem. It's recommended to put the "Application" class in a "root" package, that way the scanning will traverse child packages recursively. Otherwise, you can add a @ComponentScan to scan other packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `x` package is something like `com.example.mybootapp` and your main `Application.class` is inside `x` package then you need to add this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.mybootapp","com.example.someother","one.more.pack"})
```

on your main `Application.class` method or Configuration file.

`@SpringBootApplication` itself consists of `@Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan` annotations, so `@ComponentScan` default the `basePackge` (i.e. packages to scan) to the package of the main `Application.class` and that is why Spring is unable to detect your other `@Controlers` which are outside of main package.

If you structure your code as suggested above (locating your application class in a root package), you can add `@ComponentScan` without any arguments. All of your application components (`@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` etc.) will be automatically registered as Spring Beans.

Refer this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) on how to structure your code.

Comment: Thanks.  `@ComponentScan({"com.example.mybootapp","com.example.someother","one.more.pack"})` did the trick.